# Duplicate symbol when statically linking Qt5 libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to compile QT5 in C++ with Cmake on mac M1,

For now i can try with Fedora and it's working, but not on my mac.

This is my CMake File :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(rtype)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

set(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX "pack")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/ecs/main.cpp)

# Adding QT5 dependencies
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Network)

# Adding SFML dependencies
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics)

# Ajouter les includes pour SFML
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE
    ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Setting up the CPack generator
set(CPACK_GENERATOR ZIP) # for macOS and Linux
set(CPACK_BUNDLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_BUNDLE_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist)
set(CPACK_BUNDLE_ICON ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/icon.icns)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR NSIS) # for Windows
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "RType")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${VERSION_MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${VERSION_MINOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}")
include(CPack)

# Setting up the install targets
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES README.md
        DESTINATION .)
install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build.sh
        DESTINATION .)
```

If I transform this :

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Network)
```

to this :
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
or this :
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Network)

It's working perfectly, but with both its make this error :

```
[ 20%] Automatic MOC for target rtype
[ 20%] Built target rtype_autogen
[ 40%] Linking CXX executable /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/client/bin/rtype
duplicate symbol 'qt_apple_sharedApplication()' in:
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libQt5Core.a(qcore_mac.o)
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib//libQt5Core.a(qcore_mac.o)
duplicate symbol 'qt_apple_check_os_version()' in:
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libQt5Core.a(qcore_mac.o)
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib//libQt5Core.a(qcore_mac.o)
duplicate symbol 'qt_apple_isApplicationExtension()' in:
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libQt5Core.a(qcore_mac.o)
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib//libQt5Core.a(qcore_mac.o)
[...]
duplicate symbol 'RunLoopDebugger::staticMetaObject' in:
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_cf.o)
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib//libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_cf.o)
duplicate symbol 'QEventDispatcherCoreFoundation::staticMetaObject' in:
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_cf.o)
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib//libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_cf.o)
duplicate symbol 'QEventDispatcherCoreFoundation::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)' in:
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib/libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_cf.o)
    /Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib//libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_cf.o)
ld: 94 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/ilaan/Documents/Epitech/Tek3/R-Type/client/bin/rtype] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rtype.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't understand why, is not compatible with M1 Chipset ?

Thank you,
Ilan

Comment: You seem to be linking Qt statically instead of dynamically. Be aware you cannot redistribute this binary without also making your source code (or at least object files) public.

Comment: It looks like the Qt5Network.a static library already includes all the symbols of Qt5Core.a. For now you can get by with just linking to Qt5::Network, but you will see the same pain when you add a third Qt library. Solution: don't link statically.

Comment: I think its work with just network, but how I can create my links dynamically ?
Thanks you @Botje

Comment: How did you set up vcpkg? It appears that if you specify static in your triple it generates static libraries.

Comment: Hi, I install with git clone, I start "bootstrap-vcpkg.sh" and export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/vcpkg
Its not good ?
I need to make this project to multiplatform

Comment: Finally it doesnt work.. If i use just qt5::Network its seems..